Why failed to retrieve image with amphora tag?
When creating octavia load-balancer, the error is written in octavia-worker.log.
2024-09-01 05:31:30.382 2524 ERROR octavia.compute.drivers.nova_driver [-] Nova failed to build the instance due to: Failed to retrieve image with amphora tag.: octavia.common.exceptions.ImageGetException: Failed to retrieve image with amphora tag.


$ openstack image list --tag amphora
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+
| ID                                   | Name                | Status |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+
| c3d60e1c-074b-4f3f-83c6-c2034c0ae474 | amphora-x64-haproxy | active |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+--------+

I don't know why?

Does the image have the correct permissions/project access? According to the docs it has to be assigned to the "service" project.
